# Revealing Module pattern with arguments in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am curious if anybody has any preference on the following two ways to expose arguments in the Revealing module pattern:

Exhibit 1:

```
DocReview.DocumentsApp = (
    ((DocReview, Backbone) ->
        console.log("body")
    )(window.DocReview, window.Backbone))
```

Which compiles to

```
 DocReview.DocumentsApp = (function(DocReview, Backbone) {
    return console.log("body");
  })(window.DocReview, window.Backbone);
```

Exhibit 2:

```
DocReview.DocumentsApp = do(DocReview = window.DocReview, Backbone = window.Backbone) ->
    console.log("body")
```

Which compiles to

```
  DocReview.DocumentsApp = (function(DocReview, Backbone) {
    if (DocReview == null) DocReview = window.DocReview;
    if (Backbone == null) Backbone = window.Backbone;
    return console.log("body");
  })(DocReview, Backbone);
```

I think I compare the second way with the do keyword as it is neater coffeescript but I am not sure.

Anybody share an opinion on the matter?

Comment: I really like the do syntax. Didn't know about that one. Which is silly :D Looked it up and it appears to be the keyword for a closure wrapper. Which is basically what the module pattern is. So to me it really feels like the method to use.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
DocReview.DocumentsApp = do ({DocReview, Backbone} = window) ->
    console.log "body"
```

Compiles to:

```
DocReview.DocumentsApp = (function(_arg) {
  var Backbone, DocReview, _ref;
  _ref = _arg != null ? _arg : window, DocReview = _ref.DocReview, Backbone = _ref.Backbone;
  return console.log("body");
})({
  DocReview: DocReview,
  Backbone: Backbone
});
```

Comment: Nice.  Coffeescript assignment is one the most appealing features.